# Getting div text inside nested table td with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, axios, cheerio

Using Cheerio and axios, I am trying to get the text "Version" and "1.7.0" from the divs inside nested tds in a table from a vscode marketplace [page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bloumbs.borders-dark)

I have tried this and a bunch of other ways to pinpoint the div text at the bottom but I'm not sure that I'm addressing it correctly. I am unsure where to start to get the nested elements inside the table, and I am pretty confused. Any help on the surely simple problem is appreciated.

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');

const url = "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bloumbs.borders-dark"

axios.get(url).then((response) => {
   const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)

   // With this I get no response:
   $('.ux-table-metadata > tbody > tr > td > div').each(() => {
      console.log($(this).text());
   });

   // And with this method, it return "null"
   let version = $('.ux-table-metadata tbody tr td div').html($.versionText)
   console.log(version)
})
```

This is the section of html I'm working with:

```html
<div class="ux-section-other">
  <h3 class="itemdetails-section-header right">More Info</h3>
  <div>
    <table class="ux-table-metadata">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>Version</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>1.7.0</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the div around the table?

Comment: @Rob I don't know, its not my stuff. It's the html from a theme page on the vscode marketplace. Like [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bloumbs.borders-dark)

Comment: Does `response.data` have anything in it?  What is `$.versionText`? For that matter what is `$` here inside that function? `const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)` - if that call does NOT return "jQuery" or whatever is using that `const` named `$` as a name it might be your issue.

Comment: The `url` you have is just a web page. when I put it in a browser, is this just "example" code for some actual url on your web site?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the url is my themes page on vscodes marketplace, the html section is from the site when you select the text "1.7.0" down on the page under "More Info", and yes the response.data returns the page source. but as BlakkM9 pointed out lower down in the thread, the response.data that comes back is the static html (allowing me to grab the download count at the top of the page) but not the version number or anything lower down in the page because it isnt there in the static html. and to be honest, im literally learning the stuff on the fly right now and trying to piece it together

Comment: If you visit that page with your network panel open you can see the xhrs that it;s loading data from.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ux-table-metadata > tbody > tr > td").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("div").html());
});
```

or

```
$(".ux-table-metadata > tbody > tr > td").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).children().html());
});
```

tested with jquery

Comment: Neither option return anything for me. I've never used jQuery before and I'm just getting started learning with this Cheerio and axios stuff. Is the code in [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/SQIQcnU.png) not the correct way to use your answer? Could you possibly show me all your code to get the div text?

Comment: Thats all the code I used. Just copied the your html and added this as script
the selector is still not correct in the screenshot.

if you want to include .ux-selection-other in your selector
the selector would be
".ux-section-other .ux-table-metadata > tbody > tr > td".

**EDIT:** nevermind I can't read, your selector is correct.

maybe there is something wrong with the html you are loading in cheerio.
do you find the desired code piece when you print response.data?

Comment: Oh my god, no I don't. When I search through the pages source or print the  response.data to a file and search for "1.7.0" or the tables class name "ux-table-metadata" the html im looking for to scrape, it isn't there. There is something wrong with the html, it not even there. Thats why im returning nothing for whatever I do. I used [this](https://i.imgur.com/65c8mmh.png) for the download count at the top of the page before and assumed Id be good to grab the version info sorta the same way as well, without even looking at the source first.

Comment: just visited the site (with scripts disabled) and i guess its not working because cheerio only receives the static html but nothing that is generated by javascript.

I'd suggest you to take a look at [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

this will make the content available that is generated by scripts and relatively easy to use.

Comment: Yes, puppeteer, I'll definitely do that. Thanks for the back and fourth help on this. Even though I should've looked more carefully at the source and stuff beforehand so I wouldn't have had to post this problem. I appreciate it.